# “It is a great deal!” vs “This is a great deal!” vs “That is a great deal!” vs “Those are a great deal!”

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, pronouns

What’s the correct answer for the following question set?

> **Speaker A**: I’ll buy these rugs as a memento of our holiday.
>
> **Speaker B**: __________ a great idea!
>
> - **a**. Those are (a great idea!)
> - **b**. It’s  (a great idea!)
> - **c**. This is  (a great idea!)
> - **d**. That’s (a great idea!)

Kindly explain why Option D *That’s* is the correct answer as shown in the answer key, and why the other options are excluded!

Comment: None is grammatically incorrect. (d) is merely the most natural-sounding response, the one that is doubtless the most commonly encountered in such a context. Often, test questions are based on subjective ideas of right and wrong.

Comment: Buying the rugs is one idea so the singular is preferred. (You'd use plural to talk about the rugs not the idea e.g. "Those are too expensive.") The rest are just based on what's the commonest thing to say.

Comment: We really don't do homework here, mujdad. You need to show some effort. Also, this question if modified to show some effort by you should go on the other site: English Language Learners. You can go and read about those pronouns.

Comment: Your title asks an entirely different question from the body, which would have a different answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a stupid test - there ***is*** no "correct answer"

Answer (score 0):

In a comment Edwin Ashworth wrote:

> None is grammatically incorrect. (d) is merely the most natural-sounding response, the one that is doubtless the most commonly encountered in such a context. Often, test questions are based on subjective ideas of right and wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment StuartF wrote:

> Buying the rugs is one idea so the singular is preferred. (You'd use plural to talk about the rugs not the idea e.g. "Those are too expensive.") The rest are just based on what's the commonest thing to say.